# Is there any software which does Ring Computations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap, computational-algebra

Are there any software that is able to compute the following problems:

1. Verifying if or not a subset of a ring is an ideal.
2. Generating all ideals of a given finite ring.
3. Finding maximal multiplicative closed subset of a finite ring, etc.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488263/websites-software-for-group-computation) question previously posted, but this deals with Groups.

Answer (score 5):

For one thing, you can work with rings in GAP! [Documentation](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap56.html)

If this isn't powerful enough, maybe look into [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/index.html) or [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/). These are general-purpose computer algebra systems that have some built-in support for rings and such.

[Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) and [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/index.php) are also popular software tools, but I think they're more focused towards commutative algebra and algebraic geometry (I've never used them, though -- perhaps they do have what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Macaulay2 is good for these problems. For example for the first one, after defining the Ring, you can check is Ideal or not with "[isIdeal](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_is__Ideal.html)" command.