# Is there a website to find groups with given properties?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, online-resources

I am thinking of something like [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/) but for groups: you give it properties $A,B,C,D$ of groups (or their opposites) and the website returns a list of all the groups it knows with those properties.

This question was inspired by this other [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421498/group-of-exponential-growth-always-contains-a-free-sub-group). Counterexamples for questions like that would be much easier to find if we had such a website.

Comment: groupprops is probably what you search.

Comment: See also [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallgrp.html). And [the world of groups](http://www.grouptheory.info) and several similar pages. For computations with groups see the references also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488263/websites-software-for-group-computation).

Comment: @Peter but I don't think groupprops has a functionality that, given a list of properties, returns all the groups with those properties. I'll try to make that clear in the question

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for all those websites! Although I don't think they can do exactly what I am looking for. (Surely GAP can do it for small finite groups?)

Comment: I don't think that such sites for solving questions like you have linked are so useful in general. In fact, a reasoning is much better. The answer then at MO also says: "but it gives some general perspectives, and it justifies that many examples exist. " So we are not out for just one counterexample.

Comment: I agree that a reasoning is much better, simply I was surprised that there were no such websites about groups and wanted to know if I was missing something